# Is there a way in flutter to make a css like modal?

Tags: flutter

I'm currently developing an app, that includes a set of rules, and i want them to display when help is clicked, I have the onClick handeler figured out, but im wondering how to make a css like modal, with a close button in the corner?

I tried with the stack widget, but im not completly satisfied with the result, and im having trouble moving the inkWell splash effect on top of the colored box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `showDialog` with `AlertDialog` and position widgets inside them.

Here is the code

```
  _showDialog() {
    return showDialog(
        context: context,
        barrierDismissible: false,
        builder: (context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
            content: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text("Title", style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title),
                    // IconButton(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0), alignment: Alignment(1, 0), onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context), icon: Icon(Icons.clear))
                    InkWell(
                      child: Icon(Icons.clear),
                      onTap: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                    ),
                    // )
                  ],
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                  child: Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam viverra eros vitae neque faucibus ullamcorper. Nam lobortis hendrerit est vel malesuada. Fusce sem nisi, luctus sit amet nunc at, tempor ullamcorper leo. Donec tempor erat eget vehicula cursus. Nulla fringilla vestibulum libero. Maecenas viverra rhoncus urna ut aliquet. Donec rutrum viverra pulvinar. Nulla tempus mollis elementum. Quisque a cursus tellus, id finibus leo. Nulla facilisi. Nunc eget nibh id turpis commodo tincidunt."),
                )
              ],
            ),
          );
        });
  }
```

If you want to dismiss the dialog on the click of backdrop, set `barrierDismissible` to true.

**Note** - If you have long content then you may need to add a `ListView` inside a fixed height `Container` like below

```
Container(
   height: 150,
   child: ListView(
   itemExtent: 50.0,
   children: <Widget>[
     Text("Text 1"),
     Text("Text 2"),
     Text("Text 3"),
     Text("Text 4"),
     Text("Text 5"),
     Text("Text 6"),
     Text("Text 7"),
     Text("Text 8"),
     ],
   ),
)
```

Comment: Thank you, but is there a way to style the backgorund color and move the confirm button to the right top corner and make it an icon?

Comment: If you try my code you can see that there is a close button icon on right-top corner. You can customize the click action as per your need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use plugin **[flutter_progress_hud](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_progress_hud#-installing-tab-)**

Just make it parent to your widget page and by using of(context).show()/.dismiss() you can show it and hide it

```html
@override   Widget build(BuildContext context) {    return ProgressHUD(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      barrierColor: Color.fromRGBO(100, 100, 100, 0.25),
      borderColor: Colors.transparent,
      indicatorColor: Colors.orangeAccent,
      indicatorWidget: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      child:Scaffold(child:
      FlatButton(onPressed:()=>ProgressHUD.of(context).show()));}
```